# After nodejs installation when npm -v command is executed it says prefix -g is not recognized what the cause of this

Tags: node.js, npm

[here the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTJyf.jpg)After nodejs installation when npm -v command is executed it says prefix -g is not recognized what the cause of this.

> CALL C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe prefix -g is not recognized as
>   internal or external command node version - 8.11.3

npm version 5.6.0
windows 7 32bit

Comment: try to reinstall node

Comment: I've tried ..but same result

Comment: can you post here a screen shot?

Comment: maybe try updating npm

Comment: Are you running `node -g`? It shoud be `npm -g`.

Comment: Which command are you trying to run?

Comment: iam running npm -v

Comment: Have you checked out [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15891)? There's a few threads on github regarding this, all come down to failed installations/duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to do is:

```
1-) DISINSTALL NODE.JS

2-) DELETE THE NPM AND NPM-CACHE FOLDER in C:\Users\YOURUSER\AppData\Roaming

3-) REINSTALL NODE.JS (and be sure the ENV PATH options is selected)

4-) DOUBLE CHECK IF THE PATH TO NODE (C:\Program Files\nodejs\) is in the PATH Variables

5-) CLOSE ALL YOURS CMD and RE-OPEN IT and then TYPE node -v
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set `ENVIRONMENT` path correctly. check your environment variable.

Try this solution:

1. `npm root -g` (to see the current npm is installed) and go to that path.
2. `npm config set prefix` (to change the path)

Try to reopen terminal after that. Hope this may help you!